# CSS Selector Help To Extract First Line within TD

Tags: web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to extract each line from an address on a webpage using CSS selector.

The HTML block within the page containing the address is this

```
<tr>
<td ALIGN="right" VALIGN="top" CLASS='directsub'>Mailing Address&nbsp;</td>
<td CLASS="coltext">Name<br/>Acme Foundation
<br/>PO Box 195<br/>
Olympia&nbsp;WA&nbsp;&nbsp;98507
</td>
</tr>
```

When I am using the following selector, it is extracting the entire address starting from Acme Foundation to the ZIP code.

```
html > body > div:eq(3) > div > div > table:eq(0) > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td.coltext >
```

How do I extract each part of the address separately using CSS selectors instead of all in a single block?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with CSS because the address is divided with break tags. I would recommend using JavaScript to split the address up into individual lines.